# Matplotlib overlapping multiple charts in one pdf

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

for this code snippet

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('long.pdf')

lists = [
    ([1, 3, 6], ["bells", "whistles", "pasta"], 'title-1'), 
    ([11, 3, 6, 5], ["red", "blue", "green", "back"], 'title-2')
]

for x_list,label_list,title in lists:
    plt.figure(3, figsize=(2,2))
    # plt.axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])
    explode = (1, 0, 0, 0)
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.pie(x_list, labels=label_list, autopct="%1.1f%%")
    plt.title(title)
    # plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
    pp.savefig()

pp.close()
```

I'm getting two(would be many in practical) charts in one pdf but 2nd one is looks little bit overlapped by 1st one

I'm unable to resolve this. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are telling it to plot all of the pie graphs on top of one another.  `plt.figure(3)` always returns the figure numbered 3 and makes it your current figure.  The pyplot commands then plot to the current axes.

```
# only make the figure and axes once
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2, 2))
# set the aspect to be equal
ax.set_aspect('equal')
# do the looping
for x_list,label_list,title in lists:
    # clear the axes
    ax.cla()
    # make the pie graph
    ax.pie(x_list, labels=label_list, autopct="%1.1f%%")
    # set the title
    ax.set_title(title)
    # save the figure
    fig.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
```